# Get width of element

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nh4d3u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts)

I have a stacked area chart with a mouseover that shows a tooltip with data for that area of the chart.

I want the tooltip to be centered over the top of the area the mouse is over (the highlighted rectangle).

To center it I need the width of the tooltip.

I'm trying to do this with

```
 .on('mouseover', function(d, i){
    const tooltip = d3.select('.chart-tooltip').node();
    const tooltipWidth = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(tooltipWidth)
```

but the console.log returns 0

I think this is because the tooltip is not being displayed.

Is it possible to get the width of the tooltip.

Comment: why are you using div for the chart instead of svg's text / tspan? In any case, try playing with visibility: hidden instead of display: none

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino if OP used `visibility: hidden` the div would still take space in the page, that's not a good idea. The idiomatic approach here is `display: none;`, as OP did.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado he's using absolute positioning

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Yes, I know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `getBoundingClientRect` **after** setting the div's `html`, as well as the `display: block;`:

```
tooltipDis.html(html)
    .style("display", 'block');

const tooltipWidth = tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Here is the forked code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nh4d3u-cndykk?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts